# Bindings applied only once with Durandal 2.0

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am upgrading to Durandal 2.0, and have a strange issue. I can navigate my site, and most things work. Except that, when a view is called, bindings are applied once after activate, but that's it. After that, no bindings are applied: not in the attached hook, nor in `compositionComplete`. Anytime after the first apply, nothing happens. I have a search page, I can see the results coming to the browser, but bindings don't show them.

It's a big application, tough for me to reproduce. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Here's an extremely simple test view for which I have the pb:

```
<section id="test-view" class="view"">

<h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: v()"></h3>

<div data-bind="click: update">Update</div>
```

And the related viewmodel:

```
define(
function () {

    var v = ko.observable(Date.now());

    var activate = function() {    
    };

    var update = function () {
        console.log('update');
        console.log(Date.now());
        v(Date.now())
    }

    var vm = {
        v: v,
        update: update
    };
    return vm;
});
```

When loading the page I see the correct number. Then I can clearly see the click work in the console, but no update on the screen.

Comment: Are you using `cacheViews: false` in your composition binding in shell.html?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Bindings are not applied after X' because once the bindings are applied they are persisted.  Are you sure that there are no console errors?  Are you forgetting to populate an observable?

Comment: Indeed I am sure, this is very strange. Not sure how to make it clearer? I have an observableArray, populated in activate. This data is rendered correctly on the screen. But after that, when I can modify the data in the observableArray, this change is not reflected, ie bindings are not applied anymore. And no console error, nothing.

Comment: This is my shell composition binding: <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', alwaysTriggerAttach: 'true' }--><!--/ko--> I tried adding cacheViews: false but that didnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer. In main.js, these 2 lines were missing:

```
define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
```